# reading file text from a "Zip" file with "ZERO" compression ratio

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, c#-ziparchive

I've the below code, that `create` a new zip file, then `add entry` to this file with `NoCompression` i.e. `ZERO compression ratio` then try to read this entry as normal text.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (FileStream zipToOpen = new FileStream(@"d:\release.zip", FileMode.Create))
            {
                using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
                {
                    ZipArchiveEntry readmeEntry = archive.CreateEntry("Readme.txt", CompressionLevel.NoCompression);
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(readmeEntry.Open()))
                    {
                            writer.WriteLine("Information about this package.");
                            writer.WriteLine("========================");
                    }
                }
            }

           string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"d:\release.zip\Readme.txt");
           Console.WriteLine("Contents of WriteText.txt = {0}", text);
        }
    }
}
```

Both the zip file and its entry are created, and I can access them from the windows explorer, but once the code try to read it, it get the below error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not
>   find a part of the path 'd:\release.zip\Readme.txt'.    at
>   System.IO.Win32FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions opti ons,
>   FileStream parent)    at System.IO.Win32FileSystem.Open(String
>   fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32
>   bufferSize, FileOptions o ptions, FileStream parent)    at
>   System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)    at
>   System.IO.File.InternalReadAllText(String path, Encoding encoding)
>   at System.IO.File.ReadAllText(String path)    at
>   ConsoleApplication.Program.Main(String[] args)

Comment: Um... You can't treat a zip file as a normal directory. The path `d:\release.zip\Readme.txt` is not valid. Just because Explorer takes extra steps to let you browse there and read a text file doesn't make it an actual path. Don't believe me? Open a command prompt and type `dir d:\release.zip\Readme.txt` and see what happens. Adding the file to the zip with no compression simply means your zip file isn't as small as it could be because you've added non-compressed content to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly it should be noted that you did not create a zip file, you created an archive file with a specific compression; in your case, you created a ZIP archive with no compression.

> and I can access them from the windows explorer

I can't because I have 7zip associated with `.zip` files, so 7z opens the archive; in your case Windows Explorer is doing this for you. So when you browse to the `.zip` file and open it, Explorer treats the archive file as a folder and shows you the contents of the archive.

However, when you do this:

```
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"d:\release.zip\Readme.txt");
```

`System.IO.File.ReadAllText` will open the specific file you pass as the parameter, which in your case is `d:\release.zip\Readme.txt`. So the path attempting to be opened is: drive `D:`, folder `release.zip`, file `Readme.txt` ... since `d:\release.zip` is a **file** and not a **folder**, the path cannot be found, which is why you are getting the `DirectoryNotFoundException` exception.

To this, if you want to read the entry, just do what you did to `Create` the archive, except `Read` from the `Open`'ed archive and `.GetEntry` instead of `.CreateEntry`, example:

```
string text = string.Empty;
using (FileStream zipToOpen = new FileStream(@"c:\test\release.zip", FileMode.Open)) {
    using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Read)) {
        ZipArchiveEntry readmeEntry = archive.GetEntry("Readme.txt");
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(readmeEntry.Open())) {
            text = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Contents of WriteText.txt = {0}", text);
```

Hope that can help.